# Is there an client side API for detect whether allow user access to the server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

In IBM MobileFirst console, we are able to set Application Access form "Active" to "Access disabled", then the app will be disallow to access to the MFP server.
[image]

My question is, can we disallow user to access to the app itself ? [For example: once user launch the app, the app will pop out a message to tell user to download new version]

Is there an client side API for detect whether allow user access to the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, can we disallow user to access to the app itself ?
>   [For example: once user launch the app, the app will pop out a message
>   to tell user to download new version]

This scenario is exactly what Remote Disable is doing. You have v1 and v2 deployed on the server and you want to force your user(s) to upgrade from v1 to v2, so your set remote disable on v1... and then the user(s) are forced to confirm and upgrade.

Are you asking to do this only for singular users instead of for everyone at once?

Assuming your have implemented authentication on your application, since you know who is logging in to your backend system then you should be able to customize this by implementing the server-side code to also query the database for the version the specific user is using (you'll need to also make sure to enter this data to the database, I believe), and based on the result to have custom client-side code to fail the login and point the user to the App Store.

As you can imagine, this is not available out-of-the-box...

What is not sufficient with Remote Disable?

Comment: Let's say a user still using v1, he will receive a update request during online He choose cancel for update. Then he go for offline, but he still can access the app during offline. I want to block user access, once the apps is detected as older version.

Comment: if the app is offline, it means it cannot use any adapters or login and even if logged-in, he eventually timeout, and even so, any request to the server is limited and fail since the device is not connected. What you should do is handle the scenario where the app is "offline".

Comment: I want to block the access of entire apps, if I know the apps is older version, I disallow user to access to the app (Not only adapter). [PS: The user detect there is a update during online, then he choose cancel for update request, after that he turn off the wifi connection, he access the app, but the app still accessible [offline mode], I want the app the pop out a message, tell user to online and update the app.

Comment: There is no API for this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation, because I couldn't found any API from IBM knowledge center for this purpose.